# Javascript - Returning values from a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to return some values from a list that added some objects. Inside the loop, I'm getting the right output, but outside it, it's not working as it should. I might be failing in something basic, but I really can't find what it's going on. Here's what I have:

```
  var register = { name: "", number: "" };
  var listName = new Array();
  var listNumber = new Array();
  var listObject = new Array();

  listName.push("A");
  listName.push("B");
  listName.push("C");
  listNumber.push(1);
  listNumber.push(2);
  listNumber.push(3);

  for(var i = 0; i < listName.length; i++)
  {
     register.name = listName[i];
     register.number = listNumber[i];
     listObject.push(register);
     console.log(listObject[i].name) //"A" then "B" then "C"
     console.log(listObject[i].number) //"1" then "2" then "3"
  }

  console.log(listObject[0].name); //"C"
  console.log(listObject[1].name); //"C"
  console.log(listObject[2].name); //"C"
  console.log(listObject[0].number); //"3"
  console.log(listObject[1].number); //"3"
  console.log(listObject[2].number); //"3"
```

Thanks in advance for any further help!

Comment: There is only ever one `register` variable that gets mutated each iteration and pushed three times.

Comment: Are you aware that you can build arrays like `["A", "B", "C"]` and `[1, 2, 3]`, and even `[{name: "A", number: 1}, {name: "B", number: 2}, {name: "C", number: 3}]`?

Answer (score 1):

@CertainPerformance is correct. Your lack of understanding of object references in JavaScript is causing this error.

`register` is declared as a variable outside your loop, so its scope is outside the loop. This means that every time your loop code runs, you reset the properties on the register object, and then you push *the same object* into the array. So in your example, the `listObject` array is made up of 3 identical references to the `register` object.

Change your loop to:

```
for(let i = 0; i < listName.length; i++) {
  let register = {name: listName[i], number: listNumber[i]};

  listObject.push(register);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 1):

As said before, you have only one `register` variable which gets overriden every iteration.

You can push directly an object into listObject, without needing to declare an outer scope variable.

```
  var listName = new Array();
  var listNumber = new Array();
  var listObject = new Array();

  listName.push("A");
  listName.push("B");
  listName.push("C");
  listNumber.push(1);
  listNumber.push(2);
  listNumber.push(3);

  for(var i = 0; i < listName.length; i++)
  {
     listObject.push({ name: listName[i], number: listNumber[i] });
     console.log(listObject[i].name) //"A" then "B" then "C"
     console.log(listObject[i].number) //"1" then "2" then "3"
  }

  console.log(listObject[0].name); //"now A"
  console.log(listObject[1].name); //"now B"
  console.log(listObject[2].name); //"now C"
  console.log(listObject[0].number); //"now 1"
  console.log(listObject[1].number); //"now 2"
  console.log(listObject[2].number); //"now 3"
```

Comment: Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 1):

As the function iterates it adds a new register object. Each iteration the register objects keys and values are being updated.

Instead, create a register object each iteration and push it.

Like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < listName.length; i++)
  {
     let registerObject = {name: listName[i], number: listNumber[i]};
     listObject.push(registerObject);
     console.log(listObject[i].name) //"A" then "B" then "C"
     console.log(listObject[i].number) //"1" then "2" then "3"
  }
```